# How to display percentile stats per URL on the console

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I'm am working on writing some performance tests using Taurus & Jmeter.
After executing a set of tests on a some URLs, I see the stats on console as below.

```
19:03:40 INFO: Percentiles:
+---------------+---------------+
| Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
+---------------+---------------+
|          95.0 |         2.731 |
+---------------+---------------+
19:03:40 INFO: Request label stats:
+--------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
| label        | status |    succ | avg_rt | error |
+--------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
| /v1/brands   |   OK   | 100.00% |  2.730 |       |
| /v1/catalogs |   OK   | 100.00% |  1.522 |       |
+--------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to display other labels per URL. for ex.  percentile response time per URL.

Below are all the stats that could be captured from Taurus. (according to taurus documentation), but I couldn't figure out the configuration required to display them onto the console. Appreciate any help.

```
label - is the sample group for which this CSV line presents the stats. Empty label means total of all labels
concurrency - average number of Virtual Users
throughput - total count of all samples
succ - total count of not-failed samples
fail - total count of saved samples
avg_rt - average response time
stdev_rt - standard deviation of response time
avg_ct - average connect time if present
avg_lt - average latency if present
rc_200 - counts for specific response codes
perc_0.0 .. perc_100.0 - percentile levels for response time, 0 is also minimum response time, 100 is maximum
bytes - total download size
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into documentation on [Taurus Console Reporter](http://gettaurus.org/docs/ConsoleReporter/) it is possible to amend only the following parameters:

```
modules:
  console:
    # disable console reporter
    disable: false  # default: auto
 
    # configure screen type
    screen: console
    # valid values are:
    # - console (ncurses-based dashboard, default for *nix systems)
    # - gui (window-based dashboard, default for Windows, requires Tkinter)
    # - dummy (text output into console for non-tty cases)

    dummy-cols: 140  # width for dummy screen
    dummy-rows: 35   # height for dummy screen
```

If you can understand and write Python code you can try amending [`reporting.py`](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/1.13.0/bzt/modules/reporting.py#L217) file which is responsible for generating stats and summary table. This is a good point to start:

```
def __report_summary_labels(self, cumulative):
    data = [("label", "status", "succ", "avg_rt", "error")]
    justify = {0: "left", 1: "center", 2: "right", 3: "right", 4: "left"}

    sorted_labels = sorted(cumulative.keys())
    for sample_label in sorted_labels:
        if sample_label != "":
            data.append(self.__get_sample_element(cumulative[sample_label], sample_label))
    table = SingleTable(data) if sys.stdout.isatty() else AsciiTable(data)
    table.justify_columns = justify
    self.log.info("Request label stats:\n%s", table.table)
```

Otherwise alternatively you can use [Online Interactive Reports](http://gettaurus.org/docs/BlazemeterReporter/) or [configure your JMeter test to use Grafana and InfluxDB](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2) as 3rd-party metrics storage and visualisation systems.